# Difference between url with www and without www in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, google-analytics, dns

I have a Rails app and the client needed to add a google verification code, which is just an html file that he needs available in the root. In order to do that, I added the html file to the public folder and the file is now available at

```
examplewebsitename.com/googlee87hx82suhj9383.html
```

But if I go to

```
www.examplewebsitename.com/googlee87hx82suhj9383.html
```

I get 404.

The client says google will only find this file if is in www.example....

Where should I tackle this issue? Should the client change the default address in his Google Analytics account? Is there something in the Rails App I should do? Or is this a domain issue that should be fixed from the domain account?

The app was built in Rails 4 and is hosted on Heroku but has it's own custom domain.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not related to rails, it's related to your web server: nginx/apache, you have to change those settings

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I thought. But the question is now, where to change those settings if the site is hosted on Heroku.

Comment: @drjorgepolanco : It's still your DNS, you just make your DNS settings refer to the heroku app URI.  So you still control in DNS how it's referred to by users.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance rdnewman, but when you say my DNS settings are you talking about the domain account or the Heroku account?
Right now both example.com and www.example.com are pointing to example.herokuapp.com, and you can write either one of those three in the browser and they all work. But if I go to the html file using example.com/xxx.html it works, and if I do www.example.com/xxx.html I get 404.

Comment: @drjorgepolanco : yes, the domain account.  Usually, you'll do a CNAME record to refer to whatever your Heroku app's name is.    There is an issue with using Heroku names for a naked domain reference (i.e., with the base A record) that is discussed more here (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains), but other than you can do as you like in the DNS settings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's about dns with your server provider. What server you use?. (rackspace, digital ocean, etc...)

for example in rackspace you need add in records 'www' in hostname after in Target ip the ip of your server. This works to me for get www.example.com

(English it's not my native language)

Comment: I never use Heroku before, i hope someone else can help you.

Comment: Thanks AlexiShaggy, I appreciate the intention.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the html file available everywhere writing a route that maps the URL with a inline a Rack application:

```
get '/googlex1x2x3x45.html', to: proc { |env| [200, {}, ["google-site-verification: googlex1x2x3x4x5.html"]] }
```

Thanks anyways for your suggestions, they actually helped my thought process to find a solution.